# How to locate overfull \hbox too wide error code

Tags: warnings

I am getting many overfull \hbox(4 pt) too wide warnings in my code. But when I click on the warning, it points to a the first line of the main tex file which is a comment. And there are many such warnings which are pointing to the same comment. Since it is not pointing to the line that has the warning, I am not able to edit the code. Could you guys please provide your inputs on this?

The document class command is as follow:-

```
\documentclass[SectionMethod, ListStyleI]{TAMUthesis}
```

The log file description for one of the warnings is:-

```
[]|
  \hbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074, glue set - 1.0
  .\glue 3.0 plus 1.5 minus 1.0
.\glue 3.0 plus 1.5 minus 1.0
.\vbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074
..\hbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, glue set - 430.00739fil
....\vbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074, glue set 215.0037fil []
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
...\vbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074, glue set 215.0037fil
.....\glue(\leftskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
.....\penalty 10000
.....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0
.....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fill
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0, glue set - 430.00739fil
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
....\vbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074
.....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x430.0074, glue set 430.00739fil []
..\rule(0.0+0.0)x430.0074
..\glue 0.0
.\rule(*+*)x5.0
```

The sample code is :-

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Subheading requirements}
This is the second-order subheadings in this  document.\\


\begin{itemize}
\item Vertical spacing above and below each subheading needs to be consistent for each
level

\item Vertical spacing within a subheading with more than one line needs to be the same

\end{itemize}

First-order subheadings, which are section in this  document, must be     included in the Table of Contents, which is implemented in this TAMUthesis.\\



 \subsection{Test Subsection In This Chapter}
A chirp is a signal whose frequency increases  or decreases with time.

\begin{equation}\label{Equ. 3.1}
f(t)=f_0+k\cdot t
\end{equation}


$f_0$  is the starting frequency for sweeping in chirp. Its corresponding time   domain

function for a cosine linear chirp is;

\end{document}
```

Comment: An overfull `\hbox` can be usually clearly seen if you add the `draft` option to `\documentclass`.

Comment: @egreg I have edited the code.. How can I add draft option here?

Comment: Try `\documentclass[SectionMethod,ListStyleI,draft]{TAMUthesis}`: a black rectangle will mark the overfull boxes.

Comment: @egreg R u talking about the rectangle in the log files? If yes I still dont know which part of the log files mentions which line in the code has the warning. I have added the log file description for one of the warnings.

Comment: Guys please suggest a solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `draft` option (understood by all standard classes and so by those based on them, but also by Koma-script classes and `memoir`) adds a black rectangle next to most overfull `\hbox`es.

Sometimes, in special situations, this doesn't happen: it can happen in tables, for instance. Nonetheless, the method is usually very effective for visually finding the bad boxes.

So you can try

```
\documentclass[SectionMethod,ListStyleI,draft]{TAMUthesis}
```

If this doesn't work because the class doesn't define or inherit the option, adding

```
\setlength{\overfullrule}{5pt}
```

to the document preamble should produce the same effect.

Comment: I am still not able to understand where is the rectangle shown? Is it in the log or in the code? My question is how to find out which part of the code shows warning?

Comment: @ShraySharan In the output. It's like a punch in the eye.

Comment: Okay got it... Thanks.. I am afraid that almost every page of my 60 page document has that warning

Comment: @ShraySharan That's quite strange; does the class typeset the document in two column format?

Comment: How can I check that.. I am sorry if my questions are too basic.

Comment: Strangely even the dedications page which is just one line has a black color filled rectangle.

Comment: Can you add a small example to your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27346/discussion-between-shray-sharan-and-egreg).