# locate overfull hbox in alignment

Tags: boxes, warnings, alignment, debugging

I fail to locate the exact position of the origin of the final 4

> Overfull \hbox (36.55566pt too wide) in alignment at lines 343--343

warnings in my document.
My document is uses several `\subimport*{}{}` statements.

I am aware of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51763/121915) and this [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262935/121915) leading me to include

```latex
%% debug overful hbox
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen%
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen%
% \showboxdepth=5
% \showboxbreadth=5
\setlength{\overfullrule}{20pt}
```

in my preamble.
The output of the first two lines just gives

```
Overfull \hbox (36.55566pt too wide) in alignment at lines 343--343
 [] [] []

\hbox(0.0+0.0)x418.25555
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fill
.\unsetbox(0.0+0.0)x60.89868
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
.\unsetbox(0.0+0.0)x320.27867
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0
.\unsetbox(0.0+0.0)x73.63387
.\glue(\tabskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fill
```

which is telling me unfortunately nothing.
Also, increasing `\overfullrule` to a ridiculously high value to easier spot the bar seem to have no effect (in case of the math environment).

Any ideas?

Comment: the log would show you which file was being read and you surely can not have that many tables on line 343. Work up from the error to see the first file open `(` without a matching file close `)`  If you see `(./chapter1.tex     overfull box on line 343` the problem is on chapter 1. Similarly if you see `[3] [4] overfull box online 343 [5]` then the problem is on output page 5.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks for this hint. However the mentioned files more or less directly above have closing brackets before the warnings appear. They look like: `] [65] [66] [67]) (./file1.tex [68]
chapter E.
[69


])` which is spread over several lines. The closing brackets corresponds to the previous similar block. Then the next such block starts. After that some stuff about the `microtype` package and then the warnings.

Comment: that is normal means those files read to the end but there will be some unmatched ( denoting the currently open file and the error relates to something after page 69 if it is after [69]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Turns out that the problem is actually in the main.tex and due to the glossary, which is automatically generated from a .bib file?! I am rather certain the warnings originate from to long dimensions in the symbols column. (It was actually easier going to the closing bracket after the warnings and jumping to the matching opening bracket which is almost at the beginning of the log file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log would show you which file was being read and you surely can not have that many tables on line 343. Work up from the error to see the first file open `(` without a matching file close `)` If you see

```
(./chapter1.tex 
 ...
overfull box on line 343
```

the problem is in `chapter1.tex`.

Similarly if you see

```
[3] [4]
...
overfull box online 343
[5]
```

then the problem is on output page 5

One useful trick, if your editor shows matching brackets, is to type a `)` into the log file just before the warning message and see where the matching `(` is, that should give the filename, although the matching can be confused by `(` appearing in messages for other reasons so it can take some judgement to locate the filename not a purely automatic process, unfortunately.