# Overfull hbox due to `glossaries-extra`

Tags: boxes, warnings, alignment, debugging, glossaries-extra

As identified based on another of my questions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/580250/121915).
Warnings like

> Overfull \hbox (28.00505pt too wide) in alignment at lines 46--46

seem to be produced when using the `glossaries-extra` package.

Here is a MWE which outputs 3x the warning I mentioned.

The `test.tex` looks like

```
%!TEX root = test.tex
%!TEX program = latexmk
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!TEX spellcheck = en-US

\RequirePackage[l2tabu,orthodox]{nag}
% \RequirePackage{luatex85}
% \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,abstract=true]{scrreprt} % this is the main file
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
% \usepackage{refcheck}
% \usepackage{showkeys}
% for info on KOMA script see
% http://www.golatex.de/wiki/KOMA-Script
% fix incompatibilities of some packages with KOMA script
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.5pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{siunitx} % add SI unit convention support

\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
    symbols, % create list of symbols
    stylemods={longextra}, % load glossary-longextra.sty
    nogroupskip
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
    src={symbols}, % data in symbols.bib
    sort-field={name}, % sort by name field
    sort={letter-nocase}, % case-insensitive letter sort
    type=symbols, % put these terms in the symbols list
    field-aliases={unit=symbol},% convert unit key to symbol
    save-locations=false, % don't save location lists
    selection={all}, % print all without using
]

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\symbolname}{Unit}
\renewcommand{\glslongextraNameAlign}{c}
\renewcommand{\glslongextraSymbolAlign}{r}
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long-name-desc-sym]


\end{document}
```

and the `symbols.bib` is

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

% requires siunitx.sty

@symbol{cP,
  unit = {\si{\square\metre\per\square\second\per\kelvin}},
  name = {\ensuremath{c_P}},
  description = {Specific heat at constant pressure}
}
```

Comment: probably you should mention (as it took me a while to discover) this needs pdflatex, bib2gls, pdflatex

Comment: Ohh yes, sorry for not specifying it, one should run `bib2gls -d <path to build dir> test` inbetween.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that due to the width of the entries, the longtable used for the table is too wide.

The fixed-width description column is set in the style you are using by

```
\newcommand{\glslongextraDescAlign}{>{\raggedright}p{\glsdescwidth}}
```

So the correct solution is most likely to set `\glsdescwidth` to be 30pt less but I couldn't see where it is set (I don't know this package) and just reducing it in the preamble by 30pt had no effect so I instead I used

```
\renewcommand{\glslongextraDescAlign}{>{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr\glsdescwidth-30pt}}
```

so longtable used 30pt less than it previously used for the middle column and the table then fits the page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}
% \usepackage{refcheck}
% \usepackage{showkeys}
% for info on KOMA script see
% http://www.golatex.de/wiki/KOMA-Script
% fix incompatibilities of some packages with KOMA script
\usepackage[automark,headsepline=.5pt]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{siunitx} % add SI unit convention support

\usepackage[record,% using bib2gls
    symbols, % create list of symbols
    stylemods={longextra}, % load glossary-longextra.sty
    nogroupskip
]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
    src={symbols}, % data in symbols.bib
    sort-field={name}, % sort by name field
    sort={letter-nocase}, % case-insensitive letter sort
    type=symbols, % put these terms in the symbols list
    field-aliases={unit=symbol},% convert unit key to symbol
    save-locations=false, % don't save location lists
    selection={all}, % print all without using
]

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\symbolname}{Unit}
\renewcommand{\glslongextraNameAlign}{c}
\renewcommand{\glslongextraSymbolAlign}{r}
%
\renewcommand{\glslongextraDescAlign}{>{\raggedright}p{\dimexpr\glsdescwidth-30pt}}
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long-name-desc-sym]


\end{document}
```